# The accuracy problem of hand sign gestures recognition with using CNN in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Im working on my senior project in my university and I have only 2 days to fix this problem.I created a hand gesture recognition with using CNN in Python.I used 78000 images with 50x50px values.But I got stuck in the last part of my model.I can not improve my accuracy.When I start to train the data with 100 epochs,the first 15 epochs show 0,039 accuracy and it is horrible,because of that I'm not waiting the end of the train.Maybe it happens because of the values of conv2d or pooling because I don't know how to put the correct values into conv2d,pooling etc.

I'm new and I could not fix the problem.If you help me,I will be grateful for you

The code I wrote is given below;

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import tensorflow as tf
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from tqdm import  tqdm
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray






DATADIR = "asl_alphabet_train"

CATEGORIES = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]


X_train = []
y_train = []
X_test=[]
y_test=[]

IMG_SIZE=50
def create_training_data():
    for category in CATEGORIES:

        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)  # create path to dogs and cats
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification  (0 or a 1). 

        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):  # iterate over each image per dogs and cats
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))  # convert to array
                #new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (28, 50 ))  # resize to normalize data size
                X_train.append(img_array)  # add this to our trainingdata
                # add this to our X_train
                y_train.append(class_num)  # add this to our X_train

            except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
                pass


create_training_data()
X_train = asarray(X_train)
y_train = asarray(y_train)




"""
nsamples, nx, ny = X_train.shape
X_train = X_train.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))
"""




X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2,random_state=0)


N = y_train.size
M = y_train.max()+1

resultArray = np.zeros((N,M),int)
idx =  (np.arange(N)*M) + y_train
resultArray.ravel()[idx] = 1
y_train=resultArray




classifier=Sequential()
#convolution step
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=96, input_shape=(50,50,3), kernel_size=(11,11), padding='valid',activation="relu"))
#pooling step
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

#convolution step
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=256,kernel_size=(11,11),padding="valid",activation="relu"))
#pooling step
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=384,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="valid",activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))


#flatten step
classifier.add(Flatten())
#Dense(Fully connected step)
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=128,activation="relu"))
#Dropout to decrease the possibility of overfitting
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
#Dense to determine the output 
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim=26,activation="softmax"))

#compile step
classifier.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="categorical_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

    enter code here

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32)
filename="CNN_TEST.sav"
pickle.dump(classifier, open(filename, 'wb'))


y_pred=classifier.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred)
```

Comment: This seems quite broad. Are you looking for help with the programming itself, or is it more of a theoretical thing?

Answer (score 0):

Would recommend the following :

1) Reduce the kernel size in the first two convolutional layers of your model.

2) I believe the MaxPooling layer is not necessary after every convolutional layer. Do verify this.

3) A DropOut of 0.5 could drop out a large number of essential neurons, you might want to lower that.

4) Vary the number of epochs and see how your model performs each time.

Plot "train accuracy vs val accuracy" and "train loss vs val loss" at each attempt and see if your model overfits or underfits.